# Selenium: Different Versions between ChromeDriver and Chromium-Browser an Raspberry Pi

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, raspberry-pi, driver, chromium

I'm using the current version (86.0.4240.197) of the chromium-browser and the current version (87.0.4280.66) of the chrome driver on a raspberry pi. When I'm calling the driver in Python via

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path ='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

I'm getting the Error "selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 86.0.4240.197 with binary path /usr/bin/chromium-browser". I tried to downgrade to a version listed on https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/updates/chromium-chromedriver, but the versions could not be found.

Do you have any ideas for fixing it or downgrading the chrome driver?

Thanks in advance.
Matthias

Comment: did you try installing the webdriver as standalone, separate from chromium?

Comment: The older chrome driver versions can be manually downloaded. The 86 is here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=86.0.4240.22/  chromedriver_linux64.zip.

Comment: @Tenacious B: Thanks for your answer. We didn't try it. How can I do this?

Comment: @art_architect: We've downloaded the driver from googleapis, but the raspberry pi can't execute the binary.

Comment: you need an armhf version if you are running 32-bit raspbian `sudo apt upadate` `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` should install it

Comment: armhf version http://launchpadlibrarian.net/506883228/chromium-chromedriver_86.0.4240.198-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_armhf.deb

Comment: @art_architect Thanks for your answer, this helps me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, remove the chromedriver extension, and then go through the Electron Releases, you may have to do some trial and error to find the correct asset, but it worked for me.

https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/

IIRC (and I very well may be wrong), the release that worked for me was chromedriver-v11.2.0-linux-armv7l

https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v11.2.0/chromedriver-v11.2.0-linux-armv7l.zip

That's the direct link - again, it might not work for you, but it did for me (I'm running Chromium 86.0.4240.197 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with browser version 109.9.5414.112, and Chrome driver 113.something.
Per art_architect's comment on the original post, I wanted to share with slightly more detail (for posterity and noob-friendliness for other raspi beginners like myself) how to find and install the correct version on launchpad librarian.

Go to launchpad.net and search for "chromium-chromedriver 109 armhf" (or instead of 109 whatever your needed version of the chromedriver is to match the browser, armhf is for the 32 bit linux and was compatible with armv7l in my case)

There will be a TON of results but it seems that any result will work as long as the major version matches and is compatible with your machine. For 109 it ended up being: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/armhf/chromium-chromedriver/109.0.5414.74-0ubuntu0.18.04.14

There should be a ".deb" file on the page; copy the link address to this, and here's how to install it on your raspi:

```
mkdir chromium_install
cd chromium_install
wget {YOUR LINK HERE} #(for example: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/645948278/chromium-chromedriver_109.0.5414.74-0ubuntu0.18.04.14_armhf.deb)
sudo apt install ./{THE DOWNLOADED FILE} #(for example: sudo apt install ./chromium-chromedriver_109.0.5414.74-0ubuntu0.18.04.14_armhf.deb)
```

Finally, running this should work:

```
python3
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> chrome_options = Options()
>>> chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
>>> chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
>>> chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This tool seems extremely useful for managing packages. Huge thanks to art_architect for the resource and Matthias for the question, as it was a lot of headaches before finally seeing their solution.